# Images do not append to the <body>

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a simple list of images.

**HTML**

```
<body onload="getImg()">
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function getImg() {
  var list = document.createElement("ul");
  list.className = "img-list";
  for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      var item = document.createElement("li");
      path = "images/DT/"+i+".png";
      img.src = path;
      img.alt = "something";
      item.appendChild(img);
      list.appendChild(item);
  }
console.log(list);
window.alert(list.innerHTML);
}
```

Then in the console it seems I have the list showing but somehow the images are not showing in the webpage. Ant idea what's going on?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What do you get in your `console`?

Comment: I guess you should add some screenshots!

Comment: Try prepending a slash `/` inside  `<img src=`

Answer (score 1):

```
document.body.appendChild(list);
```

is still missing.

```js
function getImg() {
  var list = document.createElement("ul");
  list.className = "img-list";
  for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    var item = document.createElement("li");
    path = "images/DT/" + i + ".png";
    img.src = path;
    img.alt = "something";
    item.appendChild(img);
    list.appendChild(item);
  }
  document.body.appendChild(list);
}
```

```html
<body onload="getImg()"></body>
```

**Hint**

The code must be in the `<head>`

```
<head>
  <script>...</script>
</head>
<body onload="getImg()">...</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Js:

```
<script>
    function getImg() {
        var list = document.createElement("ul");
        list.className = "img-list";
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            var item = document.createElement("li");
            path = "images/DT/" + i + ".png";
            img.src = path;
            img.alt = "something";
            item.appendChild(img);
            list.appendChild(item);
        }
        console.log(list);
        document.getElementById("page").innerHTML = list.innerHTML;
    }
</script>
```

html:

```
<body id="page" onload="getImg()"></body>
```

Comment: Oh I was totally being silly and did not specify any html content. Thanks!

Comment: so use the answer below me, it would help you better